# Error in shell script : Process cannot be killed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, kill-process

Following is my script, for which I am getting an error when I try to kill a process. The error states the process does not exist:

```
select case when max(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) > to_date('$TO_EXTRACT_VALUE', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  then 0
else 1
    end
    from $ORACLE_TABLE;" > $SQL_TMP_FILE

    PID=$(ps -ef | grep sqlplus | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
    print $PID
    sleep 10  > $SQL_TMP_FILE
    kill -9 $PID > $SQL_TMP_FILE

     #echo "FILE_ID: $FILE_ID"
    check_result=$(sqlplus -S  ${ORA_USERNAME}/${ORA_PASSWORD}@$TNS_NAME < $SQL_TMP_FILE)
```

Also below is the debugged output:

```
select case when max(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) > to_date('2014-03-25 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  then 0
    else 1
        end
        from SHIPPING_TRANSACTION;
+ 1> /dw/etl/home/dev/tmp/extract/dw_da/check_shplx_stby_sync.dw_shpmt.ssa_shpmt_trans_fact_shpmt_trans.tmpfile
+ + ps -ef
+ grep sqlplus
+ head -1
+ awk {print $2}
PID=2303
+ print 2303
2303
+ sleep 10
+ 1> /dw/etl/home/dev/tmp/extract/dw_da/check_shplx_stby_sync.dw_shpmt.ssa_shpmt_trans_fact_shpmt_trans.tmpfile
+ kill -9 2303
+ 1> /dw/etl/home/dev/tmp/extract/dw_da/check_shplx_stby_sync.dw_shpmt.ssa_shpmt_trans_fact_shpmt_trans.tmpfile
kill: 2303: no such process
```

Can someone help me with this

Comment: How do you know that `grep sqlplus` isn't returning the PID of the `grep sqlplus` command? It **does**, after all, contain `sqlplus`, and that explains why it's not still running 10 seconds later.

Comment: If you want to avoid that, use `pgrep` -- don't grep through ps yourself.

Comment: Also, avoid all-uppercase variable names except when referring to environment variables or builtins -- following that rule avoids namespace collisions.

Comment: ...even better would be to start the specific sqlplus command you want this to kill in a way that records its PID or maintains a lockfile -- that way you don't risk killing other random processes that happen to have `sqlplus` in their name (say, `vi my-sqlplus-script`).

Comment: + echo
    set verify off
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set pagesize 0
    set numwidth 15

    select case when max(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) > to_date('2014-03-26 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  then 0
    else 1
        end
        from SHIPPING_TRANSACTION;
+ 1> /dw/etl/home/dev/tmp/extract/dw_shpmt/check_shplx_stby_sync.dw_shpmt.ssa_shpmt_trans_fact_shpmt_trans.tmpfile
+ pgrep sqlplus
+ PID=$
dw_adm_dev@zaisetldev01:/dw/etl/home/dev/bin >

Comment: Above is the output i get if i replace grep and ps -ef with pgrep sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

You should use `grep sqlplus | grep -v grep` or `pgrep sqlplus` instead of `grep sqlplus`
Maybe 2303 is PID of grep command, not sqlplus.

Comment: Even better than "grep |grep -v " as you can avoid the overhead of a pipe and an instance of grep: "grep [s]qlplus"  This matches "sqlplus" but not itself.